How to solve grpc error in fetching data from GA4 API (google-analytics-data api) by python
I am using this code snippet to get data from GA4:
 credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(self.credential_info)
 client = BetaAnalyticsDataAsyncClient(credentials=credentials)
 offset = 0  # Start at the first row
 limit = 100000  # Maximum number of rows to return per request
 request = RunReportRequest(
                 property=f"properties/{self.property_id}",
                 date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start, end_date=end)],
                 dimensions=[some_dimensions],
                 metrics=[some_metrics],
                 dimension_filter=None,
                 keep_empty_rows=True,
                 limit=limit,
                 offset=offset,
            )
 response = await client.run_report(request)

for some property ids it works completely fine, without any problem.
but some times, it shows me this error and crash:
    ERROR:grpc._common:Exception deserializing message!
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\TM-USER\Desktop\henry\datascience\.venv\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_common.py", line 89, in _transform
    return transformer(message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\TM-USER\Desktop\henry\datascience\.venv\Lib\site-packages\proto\message.py", line 370, in deserialize
    return cls.wrap(cls.pb().FromString(payload))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

In one specific case, if I change offset to 2000, it will work, that it shows there is something wrong in first 2000 rows of data.
I updated google-analytics-data to last version but nothing changed.
Do you know how can I fix this?

I would say it is safer if you limit your returned data by smaller numbers, since in any case you need to check nextPage info, even if you consider the limit = 100000

I did that also, but something is wrong in rows between 0 and 2000, If I put offset to 2000 it will work fine

what is your timing range   ?               date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start, end_date=end)], are you sure it does not include any future dates or dates too far in the past ? and try to print the responses to get detailed output , especially when error happens
